# Não consigo executar uma classe

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, file-upload, instanciar-objeto

Então pessoal, eu estou tentando rodar um aplicativo para fazer um upload de uma imagem para o meu servidor. Sem salvar esses dados no banco de dados, o upload ocorre normalmente, porém ao tentar incluir o link da imagem no banco de dados, o php simplesmente não executa, como se tivesse alum erro de código. Já revisei esses PHPs e meu javascript varias vezes, porém não encontro erro nenhum. fiz o script assitinndo uma video-aula e na aula tudo funciona perfeitamente, mas quando aplico no meu servidor não funciona: segue os códigos:

javascript:

```js
<script src="js/upload.min.js"></script> 
    <script>
    $('#i_ver').click(function(){ //avança para div de upload
        $('#inicia_verificacao').fadeOut(600);
        $('#doc_frente').fadeIn(600);
    });
    $('#id_frente').change(function(){ //ao selecionar imagem, envia o formulario
        $('#uploadfile').ajaxForm({
   url: 'php/conecta/docupload.php',
   type: 'post',
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#loading').show();//mensagem de loading
            },
   success: function(data){
                $('#loading').hide();//esconde loading
    alert(data);//mostra resposta do servidor
   }
  }).submit();
    });
    </script>
```

docupload.php:

```
            include_once 'conecta.php';
            session_start();

            $cpf = $_SESSION['cpf'];
            $cpfformatado = str_replace(array('.', '-'), "", $cpf);

            $pasta = "../../uploads/".basename($cpfformatado);
            $arquivo = $pasta."/".basename($_FILES['frente']['name']);

            if (!is_dir($pasta)) {
                mkdir($pasta, 0755, true);
            }
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['frente']['tmp_name'], $arquivo)) {
                $conn = new conecta();
                $conn->uploadDocumento($_FILES['frente']['name'], $arquivo, $cpf);

                $saida = array(
                    "success" => true,
                    "link" => str_replace('../..','',$arquivo)
                );
            }
            else{
                $saida = array(
                    "success" => false,
                    "erro" => 'Imagens não enviada'
                );
            }

            echo json_encode($saida);
```

conecta.php:

```
        include_once 'config.php';
        class conecta extends config{
            var $pdo;
            public function __construct(){
                $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->host.';dbname='.$this->db, $this->user, $this->pass);
            }


            public function getDocumento($cpf){
                $sobe = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT link FROM documentos WHERE cpf = :cpf");
                $run = $sobe->execute();
                $clayton = array();
                while($rs = $sobe->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    array_push($clayton,$rs['link']);
                }
                return $clayton;
            }


            public function deleteDocumento($foto, $cpf){
                $acao = $this->pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM documentos WHERE link = :foto AND cpf = :cpf');
                $acao->bindValue(':foto',$foto);
                $acao->bindValue(':cpf',$cpf);
                $run = $acao->execute();
            }


            public function uploadDocumento($nome, $foto, $cpf){
                $acao = $this->pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO documentos (id, nome, link, cpf) VALUES (NULL, :nome, :foto, :cpf)');
                $acao->bindValue(':nome',$nome);
                $acao->bindValue(':foto',$foto);
                $acao->bindValue(':cpf',$cpf);
                $acao->execute();

                $resposta = array(
                    'success' => true
                );

                return $resposta;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de pesquisar muuuuito e refazer o código varias vezes descobri que para chamar a classe e executar as funções com parâmetros "externos", é necessário char o arquivo com "requeire_once". fica ai a resposta caso alguem tenha um problema parecido.